# r function to find if condition is met and then add column with cumulative difference

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
df<-data.frame(H0=c(35.4, NA, 36.0, 36.4), H1=c(32.3, 32.0, 34.3, 33.5), 
       H2=c(33.4, 31.5, 33, 34.2), H3=c(32.9, 33.0, 34.0, 33.0),
       H4=c(32.8, NA, 34.5, 33.2))
```

I need a function that will look through each row and if the number is >32.5, store the difference, and add a fifth column with the cumulative difference for all columns in that row >32.5. NA is ignored. So I would expect the first row to give a result of 4.5.

Answer (score 3):

maybe

```
df$diff_32.5 <- apply(df, 1, function(x){sum(x[x>32.5]-32.5, na.rm=T)})

> df
    # H0   H1   H2   H3   H4 diff_32.5
# 1 35.4 32.3 33.4 32.9 32.8       4.5
# 2   NA 32.0 31.5 33.0   NA       0.5
# 3 36.0 34.3 33.0 34.0 34.5       9.3
# 4 36.4 33.5 34.2 33.0 33.2       7.8
```

*Another option with more steps:*

```
df2 <- df-32.5
df2[df2<0] <- 0
df$diff_32.5 <- rowSums(df2, na.rm=TRUE)
```